# Why text widget in flutter doesn't show with combination alphabet and number

Tags: flutter, text-widget

I want to display the text 'ellen 112@yahoo.com' in the flutter widget text, but what appears is only ellen @ yahoo.com. The same thing happens if the text alphabet is combined with numbers like email112mail which appears email mail. What happened ?

Here is the code

```dart
Positioned(
            top: 180,
            left: 40,
            right:40,
                   child:
                     Card(
                       color: Colors.yellow,
                       child: Column(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           ListView(
                             shrinkWrap: true,
                             children: <Widget>[
                               ListTile(
                                 leading: Icon(Icons.mail, color:  Color (0xff00a8f3) ,),
                                 title: Text("Email112mail",style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff00a8f3),
                                   fontFamily: 'Hello Christmas',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                                 subtitle: Text('ellen112@yahoo.com',style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff538f9d),
                                   fontFamily: 'Hello Christmas',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                               ),
                               ListTile(
                                 leading: Icon(Icons.phone_android,color:  Color (0xff00a8f3) ,),
                                 title: Text("Mobile",style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff00a8f3),
                                   fontFamily: 'Hello Christmas',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                                 subtitle: Text(mobile,style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff538f9d),
                                   fontFamily: 'FRESH_TEA-DEMO',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                               ),
                               ListTile(
                                 leading: Icon(Icons.phone,color:  Color (0xff00a8f3) ,),
                                 title: Text("Phone",style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff00a8f3),
                                   fontFamily: 'Hello Christmas',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                                 subtitle: Text(phone,style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff538f9d),
                                   fontFamily: 'FRESH_TEA-DEMO',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                               ),
                               ListTile(
                                 leading: Icon(Icons.cake,color:  Color (0xff00a8f3) ,),
                                 title: Text("Birthdate",style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff00a8f3),
                                   fontFamily: 'Hello Christmas',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                                 subtitle: Text(birthDate,style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff538f9d),
                                   fontFamily: 'FRESH_TEA-DEMO',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                               ),
                               ListTile(
                                 leading: Icon(Icons.favorite,color:  Color (0xff00a8f3) ,),
                                 title: Text("Favorite",style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff00a8f3),
                                   fontFamily: 'Hello Christmas',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                                 subtitle: Text(favorite,style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Color (0xff538f9d),
                                   fontFamily: 'Hello Christmas',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                   fontSize: 14,
                                 ),),
                               ),
                             ],
                           )
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
        )
```

This is the output

[image: Output screen see what I marked with the red box]

Comment: It is coming fine. Can you try your code without fontFamily. (Also you are using ListView inside Column)

Comment: THX!! di problem is fontfamily. I don't think that's the problem thx u :)

Comment: you can upvote the comment if it solved your problem or helped you to solve your problem